# Hosted Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Rescue Mode (no Grub) cannot reset root password

Tags: root, recovery-mode, passwd

We need to reset the root password on a remotely hosted Ubuntu VM. There is no known sudo-account available. We only can access the VM via a web-based console. Using the Shift-key at boot time to get into Grub does not seem to work. The console provided by the hosting company only has an option 'Boot Linux rescue mode'. The hosting company does not want to support us in this matter.

When using this option we find ourselves confined in the recovery environment and cannot seem to change anything on the actual VM itself.

Questions:

A. Should Shift-key boot into Grub work, even remotely via a webbrowser console?
B. How do we need to go about to successfully reset the root password on an associated VM from within the 'Boot Linux rescue mode (effectively 'SystemRescue-Cd 4.7.2')?

What we've tried to do so far:

1. Reboot having selected 'Boot Linux rescue mode'
2. Check the root file system's partition
3. Create directory /media/vda1 to mount the root file system on
4. Mount the VM's root file system on /media/vda1
5. Try to chroot to /media/vda1
6. Execute passwd root to change the root password

   - @console:

```
root@sysresccd / root % fdisk -l
```

```
...
Device      Boot    Start   End         Sectors     Size    Id  Type
/dev/vda1   *       2048    499711      497664      243M    83  Linux
/dev/vda2           501758  314570751   314068994   149.8G   5  Extended
/dev/vda5           501760  314570751   314068992   149.8G  8e  Linux LVM
...
root@sysresccd / root % mkdir /media/vda1
root@sysresccd / root % mount /dev/vda1 /media/vda1
root@sysresccd / root % ls /media/vda1
    abi-3.13.0-55-generic
    config-3.13.0-55-generic
    grub (directory)
    initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
    lost+found (directory)
    System.map-3.13.0-55-generic
    vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
```

Looks like /media/vda1 does not contain the VM's root file system.
Execute chroot /media/vda1 anayway:

```
root@sysresccd / root % chroot /dev/vda1
chroot: failed to run command /bin/zsh: no such file or directory
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: /dev/vda1 looks like /boot .. /dev/vda5 must be / (root).

Comment: Hello Soren, Thanks, I'll try that. I've tried /dev/vda2. Didn't work. Became unsure to try anything else...

Comment: According to 'fdisk -l' it's a Logical Volum Manager (LVM) partition. This means that you will have to mount the lvm partition instead of the raw disk. Run 'lvscan' to find the name of the logical volume, and then try to mount that.

Comment: We've noticed it too that it's a LVM partition and managed to get into the system to solve the problem we had on the VM.  Thanks again for your help.